# Python: if I wrap pool.apply_async commands in try...except, are they still executed in parallel?

Tags: python, exception, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, apply-async

I've taken over some code a former colleague wrote, which was frequently getting stuck when one or more parallelised functions through a `NameError` exception, which wasn't caught. (The parallelisation is handled by `multiprocessing.Pool`.) Because the exception is due to certain arguments not being defined, the only way I've been able to catch this exception is to put the `pool.apply_async` commands into `try...except` blocks, like so:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
# Define worker functions
def workerfn1(args1):
  #commands
def workerfn2(args2):
  #more commands
def workerfn3(args3):
  #even more commands

# Execute worker functions in parallel
with Pool(processes=os.cpu_count()-1) as pool:
  try:
    r1 = pool.apply_async(workerfn1, args1)
  except NameError as e:
    print("Worker function r1 failed")
    print(e)
  try:
    r2 = pool.apply_async(workerfn2, args2)
  except NameError as e:
    print("Worker function r2 failed")
    print(e)
  try:
    r3 = pool.apply_async(workerfn3, args3)
  except NameError as e:
    print("Worker function r3 failed")
    print(e)
```

Obviously, the `try...except` blocks are not parallelised, but the interpreter has to read the `apply_async` commands sequentially anyway while it assigns them to different CPUs...so will these three functions still be executed in parallel (if they don't throw the `NameError` exception), or does the use of `try...except` prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to be more careful in posting code that is not full of spelling and other errors.

Method `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async` (*not* `apply_sync`) returns a `multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult` instance. It is only when you call method `get` on this instance that you get either the return value from your worker function or any exception that occurred in your worker function is now thrown. So:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool


# Define worker functions
def workerfn1(args1):
    ...

def workerfn2(args2):
    ...

def workerfn3(args3):
    raise NameError('Some name goes here.')

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Execute worker functions in parallel
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        result1 = pool.apply_async(workerfn1, args=(1,))
        result2 = pool.apply_async(workerfn2, args=(1,))
        result3 = pool.apply_async(workerfn3, args=(1,))
        try:
            return_value1 = result1.get()
        except NameError as e:
            print("Worker function workerfn1 failed:", e)
        try:
            return_value2 = result2.get()
        except NameError as e:
            print("Worker function workerfn2 failed:", e)
        try:
            return_value3 = result3.get()
        except NameError as e:
            print("Worker function workerfn3 failed:", e)
```

Prints:

```None
Worker function workerfn3 failed: Some name goes here.
```

**Note**

Without calling `get` on the `AsyncResult` returned from `apply_async` you are not waiting for the completion of the submitted task and there is no point in surrounding the call with try/catch. When you then fall through the `with` block an implicit call to `terminate` will be done on the pool instance that will immediately kill all running pool processes and any running tasks will be halted and any tasks waiting to run will be purged. You can call `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` *within* the block and that sequence will wait for all submitted tasks to complete. But without explicitly calling `get` on the `AsyncResult` instances you will not be able to get return values or exceptions.